# How to make a left menu fixed with Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is my code:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#left-menu" data-offset="20">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <nav class="col-sm-3" id="left-menu">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                    <li><a href="#installation">Installation</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#api">API</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#demo">Demo</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="col-sm-9" id="content">
                <div id="installation">
                   <h1>Installation</h1>
                   <!-- ... -->
                </div>
                <div id="api">
                   <h1>API</h1>
                   <!-- ... -->
                </div>
                <div id="demo">
                   <h1>Demo</h1>
                   <!-- ... -->
                </div>
           </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

I want the left menu to be fixed when the user moves the scroll bar.
I tried:

```
#left-menu {
     position: fixed;
}
```

It doesn't work because the `div#content` floats over the `#left-menu`.

What am I missing?

**Bootstrap 3.3.6**

Comment: You are gonna have to put your `nav` element inside another `div`  then add the `col-sm-3` to that `div`. Hope that solves your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I was missing the `margin-left` of the `#content`:

```
#content {
   margin-left: 25%
}
```